# Don't know why my answer to homework question doesn't work

Tags: python

Question

> Define a function called `myfunc` that takes in a string, and returns a matching string where every even letter is uppercase and odd letter in lowercase.

My answer - don't know why it is not working:

```
def myfunc(*arg):
    result = ""
    i = 0
    for x in arg:
        if i%2 ==0:
            result += (x.upper())
        elif i%2 != 0:
            result += (x.lower())
        i += 1
    return(result)

myfunc('anyname')
```

Actual answer:

```
def myfunc(word):
    result = ""
    index = 0
    for letter in word:
        if index % 2 == 0:
            result += letter.lower()
        else:
            result += letter.upper()
        index += 1
    return result

myfunc('anyname')
```

Comment: `*arg` is not the same as `arg`, did you try just `arg`?

Comment: yeah it works when * is removed and when I only use arg. But why *arg should not be used?

Comment: @Vikash If you use `*arg`, then `arg` is a _tuple_ of all parameters passed (like `('anyname',)`).  Without the `*`, then `arg` is the _string_ parameter passed in (`'anyname'`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `*` from `*arg` because using `*` means:

> The special syntax *args in function definitions in python is used to pass a variable number of arguments to a function. It is used to pass a non-key worded, variable-length argument list.

But in your case we don't have to use `*` at all. So, remove `*` from there and your code is working absolutely fine.